# Issue with Retrieving Contract Address After Deployment in Hardhat

Tags: contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat

Description:

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to retrieve the contract address after deployment using Hardhat with ethers v6. Below is a summary of my setup:

```
roject Name: hardhat-simple-storage-fcc
Version: 1.0.0
License: MIT
Dependencies:
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0"
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0"
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0"
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^4.0.0"
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^2.0.0"
"@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.5.0"
"@typechain/hardhat": "^9.0.0"
"chai": "^4.2.0"
"ethers": "^6.4.0"
"hardhat": "^2.19.4"
"hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8"
"prettier": "^3.2.4"
"prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.3.1"
"solidity-coverage": "^0.8.0"
"typechain": "^8.3.0"
```

This is my code :

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  try {
    const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
    console.log("Deploying contract..");
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();

    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment(); 

    if (simpleStorage.address) {
      console.log(`Deployed contract address: ${simpleStorage.address}`);
    } else {
      console.log("Contract address not available.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deploying contract:", error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Output :

```
yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js 
yarn run v1.22.21
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ /home/amine/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
Deploying contract..
Contract address not available.
Done in 2.88s.
```

After deploying the contract using Hardhat, I'm unable to retrieve the contract address. As shown in the output, the address is reported as "not available" even though the contract deployment seems to be successful.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: try `simpleStorage.target` instead of `simpleStorage.address`